# How do I pick the closest integer to a random number?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, integer, compare

I tried to make a small game were you have to guess which number the computer will pick. The pick that is closer to the number should win. Now I don't know how to write an if/switch that compares the values and chooses the one that is closer to the `secretNumber`.

This is my current code for evaluating who won. As you can see, I can only work with winners having the exact same number as the secret one.

```
    if (user1Guess == user2Guess && user1Guess == secretGuess) {
        console.log(`TIE!`)
    } else if (user1Guess == secretNumber && user2Guess !== secretNumber){
        console.log(`Player 1 wins!`)
    } else if (user1Guess !== secretNumber && user2Guess == secretNumber) 
        {
        console.log(`Player 2 wins!`)
    };
```

Comment: On a sidenote: maybe try to be consistent with your equality operators, it's generally recommended to use the strict version (`===`) in all situations, unless you have some express reason to use the regular one (`==`). Keep in mind that `!==` is strict and `!=` is regular, now you're using both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Take the absolute value of the difference between each guess and the `secretNumber`. The closest guess will be the one whose difference is smaller:

```
const user1Diff = Math.abs(user1Guess - secretGuess);
const user2Diff = Math.abs(user2Guess - secretGuess);
if (user1Diff === user2Diff) {
  console.log('Tie');
} else if (user1Diff > user2Diff) {
  console.log('Player 2 wins');
} else {
  console.log('Player 1 wins');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You canuser `Math.abs()` to get difference between user guesses and `secretNumber` to compare and decide who wins.

Hope this snippet helps:

```js
const user1Guess = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1, // Random number between 1-100 to mock user input
  user2Guess = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1, // Random number between 1-100 to mock user input
  secretNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1, // Random number between 1-100 to mock computer pick
  user1Diff = Math.abs(user1Guess - secretNumber),
  user2Diff = Math.abs(user2Guess - secretNumber);

if (user1Diff === user2Diff) {
  console.log(`TIE!`)
} else if (user1Diff < user2Diff) {
  console.log(`Player 1 wins!`)
} else if (user1Diff > user2Diff) {
  console.log(`Player 2 wins!`)
} else {
  console.log(`You broke the game, congrats!`)
}
```

Btw, you have a typo at first `if` statement: `secretGuess` needs to be `secretNumber`

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about what it means for a guess to be closer.

If `x` is closer to `n` than `y` is. Then the distance from `x` to `n` must be less than the distance from `y` to `n`.

With numbers, the distance from `x` to `n` is `abs(n - x)`, which is the *absolute value* of the difference. The absolute value is always non-negative number. For example, the absolute value of `-3` is `3`.

So if `x` is closer to `n` than `y` is, that must mean that the following is also true:

```
Math.abs(n - x) < Math.abs(n - y)
```

You can then use these in your if statement conditions.

```
const user1Distance = Math.abs(secretNumber - user1Guess);
const user2Distance = Math.abs(secretNumber - user2Guess);

if (user1Distance === user2Distance) {
    console.log("TIE!");
} else if (user1Distance < user2Distance) {
    console.log("Player 1 wins!");
} else {
    console.log("Player 2 wins!");
}
```